# Android Select File Intent

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I'm trying to pick a file via an Intent.
What I tryed till now is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

But with this, I can only pic Photos with the galery app.

My goal is to pic ANY file via the standard file manager of Android/Samsung.

This didn't work either:

```
String manufactures = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
if(manufactures.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung"))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
}
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is to pic ANY file via the standard file manager of Android/Samsung.

Android does not have a "standard file manager".

If your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, you are welcome to use [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), which is the closest thing that Android now has to a "standard file manager".

Otherwise, you are limited to whatever `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`-supporting apps that the user has installed, or creating your own file-selection UI, or using one of [many existing libraries for selecting files](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Comment: Thx for your answer. What is just tryed i is:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
but then, the app crashes ...

Comment: @Pixel_95: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand what you are seeing, post a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide your current code along with that stack trace.

Comment: it says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" in the last line of the code, i just posted